# Delete Entity on Azure Table Storage from Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a requirement to delete old records after X days from Azure Table Storage, so I have created a Logic App for that and run on daily bases to remove old data.

I have use the Get All Entities based on the condition in filter query and then run for each with delete entity in it.

[image]

Everything is running fine except the Delete Entity, it is giving `404 Resource Not Found` error. I have used the same Partition and Row Key from For Each and also used Etag = * but still it is giving me 404.

**Input**

```
{
    "method": "delete",
    "headers": {
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    "path": "/Tables/deleteordertest/entities/etag(PartitionKey='2021-09-27T19:16:07.778815Z',RowKey='1')",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "referenceName": "azuretables"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-request-id": "11d3c7fe-3002-004a-5ed3-0d0096000000",
        "x-ms-version": "2016-05-31",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Date": "Thu, 20 Jan 2022 08:01:02 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "251",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "odata.error": {
            "code": "ResourceNotFound",
            "message": {
                "lang": "en-US",
                "value": "The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:11d3c7fe-3002-004a-5ed3-0d0096000000\nTime:2022-01-20T08:01:02.6479920Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Working on Postman**
If I try same thing in postman then it is working fine, so I don't know what can be the issue here. I have already tried to add and remove `encodeURIComponent` but no luck.

I doubt about the `:` in the PartitionKey but it is working while using Replace Entity (Merge), so it cannot be possible that it will work for one item and not for another..

*If any one can help me here or guide me for any alternative.*

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end found that the reason that you are receiving a 404 status code because of removing `encodeURIComponent` which will be refering to the entity that we are retrieving. After adding the `encodeURIComponent` in `Get entities` action solved the error.

Here is my logic app

[image]

Here is the codeview of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Delete_Entity_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "headers": {
                                "If-Match": "*"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "azuretables"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "delete",
                            "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('Table2408')}/entities/etag(PartitionKey='@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['PartitionKey'])}',RowKey='@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['RowKey'])}')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_entities')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_entities": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_entities": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "azuretables"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('Table2408')}/entities",
                    "queries": {
                        "$filter": "PartitionKey le '5'"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Here is the output :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I had tried both - adding `encodeURIComponent` and removing `encodeURIComponent` also.. can you just change the partitionkey to UTC Datetime like `'2021-09-27T19:16:07.778815Z'` and retry, I guess after then you can reproduce my problem..

Comment: Have you tried for the previous step instead of using adding `encodeURIComponent` for Delete Entity.(i.e.. Get Non failed order than)

Comment: as I have said, I had tried everything.. by using `encodeURIComponent` and also by removing `encodeURIComponent` .. but still I will try again today and let you know .. incase if I want to show you my sample app, how can I show you?

Comment: Code=`"path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('deleteordertest')}/entities/etag(PartitionKey='@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_order')?['PartitionKey'])}',RowKey='@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_order')?['RowKey'])}')"` and RawInput= `  "path": "/Tables/deleteordertest/entities/etag(PartitionKey='2021-09-27T19%3A16%3A07.778815Z',RowKey='1')", `

**Didn't work**

Comment: Code=`"path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('deleteordertest')}/entities/etag(PartitionKey='@{items('For_each_order')?['PartitionKey']}',RowKey='@{items('For_each_order')?['RowKey']}')"` and RawInput= `      "path": "/Tables/deleteordertest/entities/etag(PartitionKey='2021-09-27T19:16:07.778815Z',RowKey='1')", `
**Didn't work**

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` was already there in Get_non-Failed_orders_older_than step.. `"path": "/Tables/@{encodeURIComponent('deleteordertest')}/entities",`  **Can you try with setting PartitionKey='2021-09-27T19:16:07.778815Z' and RowKey='1'?**

Comment: @Sachin Yes, even giving **PartitionKey='2021-09-27T19:16:07.778815Z' and RowKey='1'** has worked for me

Comment: This is probably because you are trying to delete already deleted entity. Can you please try with other entity that is present in your table?

Comment: You have to remember that this is going to get succeded only one and the rest gets failure runs because , while in recurrance it first deletes the entity and then again it tries to dete in the second run which already got deleted. Thats the reason why you are receiving ResourceNotFound error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242076/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-mt-and-sachin).